# Using d3.js svg clipPath not clipping in Angular

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js

I am developing a graph that's vey similar to following example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 where it uses clipPath to clip the area so the area graph does not overflow the axis.

Using the same example in an Angular directive it works almost all properly but the clipping. When using the focus feature, the line from the graph overflows the limits of the clip rectangle.

But the same code in jsFiddle works properly http://jsfiddle.net/gserra/TXYGH/. The mentioned code in the Directive is the following:

```
angular.module('casApp.directives', []).
  directive('lineChart', ['d3', '_', 'moment', function (d3, _, moment) {
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40};
    var margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40};

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        data: '=',
        stream: '=',
        start: '=',
        end: '=',
        period: '@',
        unit: '@',
        sensor: '@',
        width: '@',
        height: '@'
      },
      template: '<div class="line-chart"></div>',
      controller:'DataCtrl',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        var height = scope.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          height2 = scope.height - margin2.top - margin2.bottom,
          width = scope.width - margin.left - margin.right;

        scope.updateTime();

        var x = d3.time.scale()
          .domain([scope.start, scope.end])
          .range([0, width]);

        var x2 = d3.time.scale()
          .domain(x.domain())
          .range([0, width]);

        var min = d3.min(scope.data, function (d) {return d.value; })
        var max = d3.max(scope.data, function (d) {return d.value; })
        var thres = Math.abs(max-min);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([min - thres, max + thres])
          .range([height, 0]);

        var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain(y.domain())
          .range([height2, 0]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function (d) {
            return x(moment(d.at));
          })
          .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.value);
          });

        var line2 = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function (d) {
            return x2(moment(d.at));
          })
          .y(function (d) {
            return y2(d.value);
          });

        var graph = d3.select(element[0])
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', scope.width)
          .attr('height', scope.height);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'),
          xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient('bottom'),
          yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left');

        var brush = d3.svg.brush()
          .x(x2)
          .on('brush', brushed);

        var focus = graph.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        var context = graph.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin2.left + ',' + margin2.top + ')');

        focus.append('defs').append('clipPath')
          .attr('id', 'clip')
          .append('rect')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height);

        focus.append('g')
          .data([scope.data])
          .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', line)
          .attr('class', 'line');

        focus.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'x axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
          .call(xAxis);

        focus.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'y axis')
          .call(yAxis);

        context.append('path')
          .data([scope.data])
          .attr('d', line2)
          .attr('class', 'line');

        context.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'x axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height2 + ')')
          .call(xAxis2);

        context.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'x brush')
          .call(brush)
          .selectAll('rect')
          .attr('y', -6)
          .attr('height', height2 + 7);

        function brushed() {
          x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
          focus.select('path.line').attr('d', line);
          focus.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
        }

        function updateGraph () {
           // update x axis
          x.domain([scope.start, scope.end]);
          x2.domain([scope.start, scope.end]);
          xAxis.scale(x);
          xAxis2.scale(x2);

          focus.selectAll('g.x.axis').call(xAxis);
          context.selectAll('g.x.axis').call(xAxis2);

          // update y axis
          var min = d3.min(scope.data, function (d) {return d.value; })
          var max = d3.max(scope.data, function (d) {return d.value; })
          var thres = Math.abs(max-min);

          y.domain([min - thres, max + thres]);
          y2.domain([min - thres, max + thres]);

          yAxis.scale(y);

          focus.selectAll('g.y.axis').call(yAxis);

          //update line
          focus.selectAll('path.line')
            .data([scope.data])
            .attr('d', line);

          context.selectAll('path.line')
            .data([scope.data])
            .attr('d', line2);
        }

        scope.$watch('data', function () {
          var last = scope.data.length > 0 ? moment(_.last(scope.data).at) : null;

          if (last && last > scope.end) {
            scope.updateTime(last, moment(last).add(scope.unit, scope.period));
            scope.data = [_.last(scope.data)];
          }
          updateGraph();
        });
      }
    };
  }]).

  directive('paginator', function () {
    return {
      controller: 'DataCtrl',
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<button class="forward" ng-disabled="stream" ng-click="forward()">Page up</button>' +
                '<button class="back" ng-click="back()">Page down</button>'
    };
  });
```

The graph is updated automatically using socket.io in a controller. I've tried without success to attach defs to "svg" instead of "g". Any ideas?

I am using Angular 1.2.2

Comment: Have you verified that the SVG generated by angular contains the `defs`?

Comment: Yes, the code in jsfiddle is a copy&paste from the angular output.

Answer (score 11):

Finally after isolating the code in another file and simplifing it, I've found what was the responsible of this strange behaviour:

In the `<head>` I had:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <title>Real time context aware graphics display</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/graph.css"><base href="/">
  <base href="/">
  <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
```

Ad when I removed the `<base href="/">` all worked perfectly. I do not know exactly the reason.

Comment: You've specified a relative URL - `url(#clip)` this is expanded into an absolute URL and the base directive changes the way that works.

Comment: @RobertLongson I need `<base href="/">` in my project. I also want to use clipPaths. How would you solve that?

Comment: Ok :-) The question is **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430111/svg-clippath-in-angularjs-app-with-base-directive)**.

Comment: The workaround I used was to add the relative URL before `#clip` by either `'url(' + $location.path() + '#clip)'` to the controller, or if you need it in html, add `$scope.path = $location.path()` to the controller and `clip-path="url({{path}}#clip)"` to the element.

Comment: One more little addition to @morloch 's answer: if you have a '?' and query params in the url (aka search values) you'll need to use $locaiton.url() instead of $location.path(). 
It will look something likes this: url($location.url() + #clip)