# Why d3 chart exceeds the boundaries of the chart area?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

My d3 codes are alomost like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/npzjLng9/2/), in this example, the brush functionality works pretty well.

However, when I just copy and paste the `<script>...</script>` part of the above example into my `index.js` file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <title>Hello world!</title>
  <base href='/'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <!--some more script here-->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!--navbar here-->
  </nav>

  <div ng-view> </div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
  // exactly the same code in the above d3 brush example 
</script>
```

The d3 brush function works as follows, i.e, the lines get outside of the axis area. My css file is the same as that in the above example. I guess it has something to do with angularjs or bootstrap?

Please advise, thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem happens because the SVG clip-path fails. It fails because of the `<base href = '/'>` tag. SVG clip-path attribute requires url, which is not well provided by this base tag (HTML 5 mode).

There are two solutions. One straightforward way is not using HTML5 mode, i.e, try to remove/modify the base tag. But this solution has some problems, like if the absolute url of propeties changes frequently, then we definitely need base tag to set a relative path.

Another solution is preferred. That is to set an absolute url for SVG `clip-path`, instead of asking help from the base tag, i.e,

In the controller, add

```
var vm = this;
vm.path = $location.path();
```

or just

```
$scope.path = $location.path();
```

then change every

```
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
```

to be

```
.attr("clip-path", "url(" + ctrl.path + "#clip)")
```

then all done.

Actullay this problem is solved in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430111/svg-clippath-in-angularjs-app-with-html-base-element), which is also my reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the top line of `<base href='/'>` if you remove that line the page will work ok or remove "/". It changes the context path to load your css file and other scripts. Look at [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8j54fI4tBDSewMloOnW?p=preview) to preview the working script.

EDIT : 
If you need to keep "base href" line then can you include your style.css in the head section? Look at this [modified link](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8j54fI4tBDSewMloOnW?p=preview).

```
<head>
  <title>Hello world!</title>

 <base href=''>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you@D3_GXT_Java This solution requires remove or modification of `<base href = '/'>` which is important for my rest codes, if I change it, all the other codes should be updated and not sure if it will case any other problem. Any other solution that can help me leave the `<base href='/'>` unchanged?

Comment: Check the edited answer - if you can include your style css in the head section it should work.

Comment: It does not work well when the css is put in the head. The modified link shows exactly the same problem I have now. Does that work in your side?@D3_GXT_Java

Comment: pls see the new screenshot I attached. I think you are right, the <base> tag is the reason, here is a useful [reference](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8934) @D3_GXT_Java

Comment: thanks for your hints, it is solved, pls see my answer. @D3_GXT_Java